# database relational algebra , sql query

Tags: database, relational-algebra

5.Consider the following library schema

```
Books (book_no,title,authors,publisher)
Borrower(borrower_id, name, DOB, job)
Borrowed(borrower_id,book_no,date)
```

Write the following queries in relational algebra

- a. Find the name and the borrower_id of borrowers who have borrowed more than 3 books published by “Wiley”
- b. Find the names of borrowers who have borrowed any book published by “wiley”
- c. Find the average number of books borrowed by each borrowers,.

Comment: what you have tried  so far??

Comment: What's your problem? What did you try so far?

Comment: a. you need to join the tables and do group by operation and give condition Wiley, b. simply give condition by joining required tables, c. same as 'a' but no need of condition and just take count

Comment: And all these need to be done in **relational algebra**, not **SQL**. I think you will benefit the most if you answer these questions yourself. Happy learning!

Comment: Please give a reference to the "relational algebra" you are supposed to use. There are many. The accepted answer is (still) SQL not any common relational algebra variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your question, sql query is like this

For question 1

```
select B.borrower_id, B.name 
  from Borrower as B, Borrowed as Bw, Books as Bk
 where B.borrower_id = Bw.borrower_id
   and Bw.book_no = Bk.book_no
   and Bk.publisher = 'Wiley'
group by B.borrower_id, B.name 
having count(Bw.borrower_id) > 3
```

For question 2

```
select B.name 
  from Borrower as B, Borrowed as Bw, Books as Bk
 where B.borrower_id = Bw.borrower_id
   and Bw.book_no = Bk.book_no
   and Bk.publisher = 'Wiley'
  group by B.name
```

For question 3

```
select B.borrower_id, B.name, count(Bw.borrower_id) as cnt 
  from Borrower as B, Borrowed as Bw, Books as Bk
 where B.borrower_id = Bw.borrower_id
   and Bw.book_no = Bk.book_no
group by B.borrower_id, B.name
```

Comment: This is still SQL & not any common relational algebra variant.